# Show Y axis value on category axis in amcharts solid gauge

Tags: angular, amcharts, amcharts4

Html :

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Css:

```
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Ts:

```
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);


var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.RadarChart);


chart.data = [{
  "category": "Research",
  "value": 80,
  "full": 100
}, {
  "category": "Marketing",
  "value": 35,
  "full": 100
}, {
  "category": "Distribution",
  "value": 92,
  "full": 100
}];

chart.startAngle = -90;
chart.endAngle = 180;
chart.innerRadius = am4core.percent(20);

var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
  return (target.dataItem.index >= 0) ? chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index) : fill;
});

var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 100;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;


var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarColumnSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueX = "full";
series1.dataFields.categoryY = "category";
series1.clustered = false;
series1.columns.template.fill = new am4core.InterfaceColorSet().getFor("alternativeBackground");

var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarColumnSeries());
series2.dataFields.valueX = "value";
series2.dataFields.categoryY = "category";
series2.columns.template.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
  return chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index);
});
```

Output :

[image]

What I want :

[image]

Value should be displayed along with the category...User should not over on the graph to see the values.
I dont want tooltip to see the value.....

Anyone know how to do this....

Thanks...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your code, it will help
check [amchart label bullets](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/using-label-bullets-on-a-horizontal-bar-chart/)

```
var valueLabel = series2.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
valueLabel.label.text = "{value}";
valueLabel.locationX = 1;
```